# How to get datatable row values and route to another function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, typescript, datatable

If I use arrow functions I am able to route to another component, but I am unable to get datatable values, below is the code:

```js
$('#list-country tbody').on('click', '.fa-edit', function() {
  var tr = $(this).closest("tr");
  var data = $("#list-country").DataTable().row(tr).data();
  console.log(data);
  this.router.navigate(['/apps/edit-country']);
  this.routePage();
});
```

If I use normal functions I am able to fetch values , but i am unable to route, below is the code:

```
$('#list-country tbody').on('click', '.fa-edit', () => {

  var tr = $(this).closest("tr");
  var data = $("#list-country").DataTable().row(tr).data();
  console.log(data);
  this.routePage();
});
```

These functions are inside `ngInit()`.

Answer (score 0):

This solution might be useful for you:

1. First declare a variable in you global scope(method / class)
2. Initialize it to `this` in constructor(if u have any)
3. Use `self` in place of `this` as shown below

   ```
    var self = this;  //declare this in constructor or method

    $('#list-country tbody').on( 'click', '.fa-edit', function ()  {
              var tr = $(this).closest("tr");
              var data = $("#list-country").DataTable().row(tr).data();
              console.log(data);
              self.router.navigate(['/apps/edit-country']);
              self.routePage();
          });
   ```

Answer (score 0):

```
// event use direct "currentTarget"

$('#list-country tbody').on('click', '.fa-edit', event => {
  var tr = $(event.currentTarget).closest('tr')
  var data = $('#list-country')
    .DataTable()
    .row(tr)
    .data()

  this.router.navigate(['/apps/edit-country']);
  this.routePage()
})
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.